# Add feature type to path tag as an attribute in D3

Tags: d3.js

In this page [GeoJson map of Colombia](https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/43c7656821069d00dcbc), it uses [D3](https://d3js.org/) and geojson file to show a map.

In function below:

```
d3.json('colombia.geo.json', function(error, mapData) {
var features = mapData.features;

// Update color scale domain based on data
color.domain([0, d3.max(features, nameLength)]);

// Draw each province as a path
mapLayer.selectAll('path')
  .data(features)
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
  .style('fill', fillFn)
  .on('mouseover', mouseover)
  .on('mouseout', mouseout)
  .on('click', clicked);
});
```

I want to add the type of each feature (Polygon) as an attribute to path.

```
.attr('attribute', mapData.features.????)
```

How to get type from 'mapData.features'?

Comment: I checked the data and it seems like the type is a part of the `geometry` object. So can you try adding `.attr('attribute', function(d) { return d.geometry && d.geometry.type; });` and let me know if that works?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tested it. It works well. It can be answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *type* that you're looking for is a part of the geometry object.

```
.attr('attribute', function(d) { return d.geometry && d.geometry.type; })
```

will do the trick.

Comment: ; should be removed in the last.

Comment: Done. If you think that's the right answer, it'd be great if you could accept it so that the issue can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Thank you again.